# Receiver not working

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, linkify

I am trying to catch the open URL intent from link click on TextView to handle URL on own than to prevent from opening the default browser app chooser.

Receiver inside MANIFEST file:

```
<receiver android:name=".util.toolbox.LinkClickReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter
        android:priority="300">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver Class:

```
public class LinkClickReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, intent.getDataString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

Textview to linkify text:

```
Linkify.addLinks(noteView, Linkify.ALL);
```

I am not able to get Inside onReceive() method? Not able to show Toast too.

Comment: Have you registered your receiver in your Activity that declared your LinkClickReceiver?

Comment: how do you start your receiver?

Comment: what are trying achieve ?

Comment: @linhbeopr0 If declaring in android manifest, we need not register inside activity. here is the source to see for it : http://hmkcode.com/android-sending-receiving-custom-broadcasts

Comment: @Saret above link i shared clears you question too i guess

Comment: @sush I am trying to handle the click by my own. I may do copy url from it or I may direct to webview on some other activity or else.

Comment: @Geet pls re-check the tutorial, I see they also register the receiver in onResume of the activity.

Comment: @linhbeopr0 I just re-checked and found the **NOTE** just above 7th point of "Get Activity Context Workaround"

Answer (score 0):

Register your receiver in your activity, for example:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.VIEW");
registerReceiver(new LinkClickReceiver(), filter);
```

Remember to `unregister` when destroy your activity.

Comment: This should be as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code given

```
    public static final String BROADCAST = "PACKAGE_NAME.android.action.broadcast";
     TextView myTextView = Textoo
            .config((TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view))
            .linkifyEmailAddresses()
            .linkifyMapAddresses()
            .linkifyPhoneNumbers()
            .linkifyWebUrls()  // or just .linkifyAll()
            .linkify(patternSettings, "internal://settings/")
            .linkify(patternGoogle, "http://www.google.ie/search2?q=", null, transformFilter)
            .linkify(patternGoogle, "http://www.google.ie/search3?q=", matchFilter, transformFilter)
            .addLinksHandler(new LinksHandler() {
                @Override
                public boolean onClick(View view, String url) {
                    if ("internal://settings/location".equals(url)) {

//REGISTER RECIVER
                 IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST);
                 registerReceiver( myReceiver , intentFilter);
                  return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            })
            .apply();
```

AndroidManifest.xml register receiver :

```
    <receiver android:name=".util.toolbox.LinkClickReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter
            android:priority="300">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <action android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.android.action.broadcast"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Hi I don't need any library support to accomplish it. btw Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi I figured around the reason why not able to run code inside onReceive() method. Linkify is to make TextView string (with given pattern) into Clickable Links. So by default, the action of onClick is to throw an Activity Intent, to start those activities whose intent-filters listening for browsable category intents and show app-chooser with respective browsers available inside Android device.

**Here is why Receiver is not working, because BroadcastReceivers do not listen to activity start intents.**

So I have come around a solution by overriding the onStartActivity() method and do my handling stuff. Here is the code:

```
@Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
        boolean handleLink = false;

        if (TextUtils.equals(intent.getAction(), Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {

            if (matchesPattern(intent.getDataString())) 
            {
                //Do what you want to do from here with intent
                handleLink = true;
            }
        }

        if (!handleLink)
            super.startActivity(intent);
    }

 public boolean matchesPattern(String link)
    {
        final Pattern pattern = /*Pattern for all forms of website*/;
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(link);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
```